# Plural subject, plural object

Tags: grammatical-number, subjects, objects

My question is a bit hard to explain, but I was wondering about whether or not there was a rule for how subject and objects should be pluralized. This is the sentence that sparked my curiosity:

> ... **thin strips** of metal lined every other tread.

For context, there is a metal strip or bump on every other stair in a staircase. It's just decorative architecture. Anyways, take a look at this second example, which is a rewrite of the first.

> ... **a thin strip** of metal lined every other tread.

The meaning is the same, but the subject noun is singular rather than plural.
I have looked at other questions, but I cannot understand and apply those answers to this sentence. Pardon my lack of sense, but is there a **rule** for when the subject and object both need to be plural, and **how can I tell** which I should use?

Comment: The meaning is not the same to me. In the first sentence, there are multiple metal strips per alternating step on the staircase. In the second, there's only one strip per alternating step.

Comment: There is no rule which says that subject and object have to correspond in number. Otherwise how would you say *I caught two fish*? However care has to be taken to avoid ambiguity in cases such as you are citing. *Thin strips of metal lined every tread* could mean there were one or multiple strips on each tread. The second sentence makes the position perfectly clear.

Comment: Or that there was a metal lining for every tread except the one in question.

Comment: @deadrat Indeed! And that ambiguity could persist with the second sentence. It would be better to say *every second tread* or *alternate treads*. Using *every other* in this context often throws up that problem.

Comment: I heard an example of this ambiguity on TV only this morning: the reporter spoke of "(Somethings) every day" and I thought it should have been "A (something) every day" to make it clear that there was only one at a time.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That makes a lot of sense and helps clear things up. Now I know which one would be better. Thanks!
You as well, deadrat; I didn't even think of that meaning. I wouldn't interpret it that way because no particular step was specified in the preceding text, but I do understand how it could be ambiguous.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, if there were one 'case of measles' each day for a week, it would probably be correct for the doctor to say 'We were getting cases every day', but it would be misleading. It is the sort of thing lawyers are paid to spot.